# Need VLan to route to Internet

Tags: cisco, vlan

I have a Sangoma box here. This is Lync in a box... There is AAR Reverse proxy (VM) on the server and it has an IP of 10.10.9.7 on The "External" interface. I have 10.10.10.5 on the "Internal" interface. I have a the host machine has IP 10.10.10.34 on the "Virtual Internal" interface and the "External" has no IP but is connected to Cisco SG300 actually they both are. The "Internal" interface is part of VLan 10. The "External" is connected to VLan 9. The IP of VLan 9 interface is 10.10.9.1. The IP of VLan 10 is 10.10.10.1.

I can ping VLan 9 from the External interfaces but can not ping the internet. The Cisco SG300 is in Layer2 mode but it hands off to a Cisco 3560 Where I have a Port on VLan 9 and it plugs into the X2 port of my sonicwall. Sonicwall X2 IP is 10.10.9.2 and can ping 10.10.9.1 but no farther. I need help I am not a cisco person. If there is any other information you need just ask.

---

This is most of them. This is the show ip route:

```
Gateway of last resort is 10.10.30.2 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 10.10.30.2
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 24 subnets, 2 masks

R        10.10.0.0/24 [120/1] via 10.10.30.2, 00:00:14, Vlan30

C        10.10.9.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan9

L        10.10.9.1/32 is directly connected, Vlan9

C        10.10.10.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan10

L        10.10.10.1/32 is directly connected, Vlan10

R        10.10.11.0/24 [120/2] via 10.10.30.2, 00:00:14, Vlan30

R        10.10.12.0/24 [120/3] via 10.10.30.2, 00:00:14, Vlan30

R        10.10.13.0/24 [120/3] via 10.10.30.2, 00:00:14, Vlan30

R        10.10.14.0/24 [120/3] via 10.10.30.2, 00:00:14, Vlan30

R        10.10.26.0/24 [120/3] via 10.10.30.2, 00:00:14, Vlan30

C        10.10.30.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan30

L        10.10.30.1/32 is directly connected, Vlan30

R        10.10.40.0/24 [120/2] via 10.10.30.2, 00:00:14, Vlan30

R        10.10.140.0/24 [120/2] via 10.10.30.2, 00:00:14, Vlan30

C        10.135.169.0/24 is directly connected, Vlan1

L        10.135.169.22/32 is directly connected, Vlan1
```

Comment: A diagram would be most helpful here.

Comment: How do you attach a diagram?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like 10.10.9.1, the gateway of your "external" VLAN, is the VLAN interface of the Cisco 3560.  This managed switch is doing some Layer 3 routing alongside Layer 2 switching.  If you can get into the elevated prompt of the Cisco command line, you should:

Get the list of interface names, to be used in later commands:

```
show interfaces brief
```

Ensure that the interface connecting to the SG300 is configured for an access VLAN:

```
show run int [interface of port that connects to SG300, such as FastEthernet1/10]
```

Look at the routing table, check for default routes or anything out of place:

```
show ip route
```

And, crucially, set a default route:

```
config t
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.9.2
```

This will tell the managed Cisco switch that any traffic on the 10.10.9.0/24 VLAN that is heading outside of the network should go through the SonicWALL IP.

Comment: This is what "show ip route" displays on the 3560:

Comment: the SG300 is in layer mode do I need to change it to layer 3?

Comment: No, and I am not even sure that switch has Layer 3 capabilities. Your `show ip route` says that 10.10.30.2 on VLAN 30 is your current gateway. You should change that to what I posted, but is there maybe a reason for that configuration? Wouldn't want to break something else in order to fix this.

Comment: Yes that route of last resort is for all the other VLans how do I get around that?

Comment: Can I set a route telling the switch that the 10.10.9.0/24 network goes out a specific port?

Comment: You should be fine by changing the gateway of last resort.  Right now those other VLANs probably can't reach the Internet either, unless they have another connection to another port on the SonicWALL or something.  You can't tell the switch 10.10.9.0/24 is on a specific port -- it already knows it is out specific virtual port VLAN9, whose physical ports are known by "show vlan id 9"